# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view',in urls.py

Tags: python, django, web, django-views

I written this logic in my views.py, and I used class based views, Detail view:

```
@login_required
class profileView(DetailView):
    model = profile
    template_name = "users/profile.html"
```

and in urls.py file I've written this:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from .views import profileView

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/',views.register,name="register"),
    path('login/',views.login_user,name="login_user"),
    path('profile/',profileView.as_view(),name="profile_view"),
]
```

the django version that I'm using is 3.1 and python version is 3.8.

I hope that someone has an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make use of `@login_required` for a class-based view, since that returns a function. You use the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class profileView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = profile
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
```